# Regex to say that string starts with pattern

Tags: regex

Is it possible to write a regex to check that a string starts with:

- 3 digits
- either `-` or `+`
- 4 digits
- either `-` or `+`
- 2 digits

Examples of strings the pattern should match:

- '123-1234-12'
- '123-1234-'
- '123-1234'
- '123-'
- '123'

Examples of strings that the pattern should not match:

- '1231234-12'
- '123-123412'
- '123--12'

---

Here's some Python code I've written which accomplishes the same thing. Just wondering though, it is possible to do this with a regular expression?

```py
import re
def match(string):
    for sep1 in ('-', '+'):
        for sep2 in ('-', '+'):
            if re.search(fr'^\d{{3}}$', string):
                return True
            elif re.search(fr'^\d{{3}}\{sep1}$', string):
                return True
            elif re.search(fr'^\d{{3}}\{sep1}\d{{4}}$', string):
                return True
            elif re.search(fr'^\d{{3}}\{sep1}\d{{4}}\{sep2}$', string):
                return True
            elif re.search(fr'^\d{{3}}\{sep1}\d{{4}}\{sep2}\d{{2}}$', string):
                return True
    return False

expected_pass = [
    '123-1234-12',
    '123-1234-',
    '123-1234',
    '123-',
    '123',
]
for string in expected_pass:
    print('expected pass', match(string))

expected_fail = [
    '123-123412',
    '1231234-12',
    '123--12',
]
for string in expected_fail:
    print('expected fail', match(string))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*Examples of strings that don't match*"? Are these examples that currently don't match but should match, or are these examples that the regex should never match?

Comment: that shouldn't match

Comment: the Python code I've posted does the correct thing. I'm just wondering if there's a way to write it as a single regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this one:

```
^\d{3}(?:[\-+](?:\d{4}(?:[\-+](?:\d{2})?)?)?)?$
```

Regex Explanation:

- `^`: start of string
- `\d{3}`: starts with three digits
- `(?:[\-+] ... )?`: optional `-` or `+`
- `(?:\d{4} ... )?`: further optional 4 digits
- `(?:[\-+] ... )?`: even further optional `-` or `+`
- `(?:\d{2} ... )?`: even more further optional 2 digits
- `$`: end of string

Check the regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/qEETOT/1).

---

Your Python code would become:

```
import re

pattern = r'^\d{3}(?:[\-+](?:\d{4}(?:[\-+](?:\d{2})?)?)?)?$'

expected_pass = ['123-1234-12', '123-1234-', '123-1234', '123-', '123']
for string in expected_pass:
    string_match = re.match(pattern, string)
    print('expected pass', string_match)

expected_fail = ['123-123412', '1231234-12', '123--12']
for string in expected_fail:
    string_match = re.match(pattern, string)
    print('expected fail', string_match)
```

Check the python demo [here](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/0rrhzh4JlsL).